# executing INSERT commands in a row very slow

Tags: sqlite

I created the SQL for creating and filling a table in a large existing SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
...
```

Then sent it to sqlite3. Irrespective of what way I read the commands (e.g. "sqlite3 db < create.sql", or ".read create.sql" in the SQLite prompt), executing each line took close to a second, even though each line only consisted of two strings.

What is causing SQLite to work so slowly? How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the list of INSERT statements into a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
...
COMMIT;
```

This will dramatically reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 2):

`inserts` can be slow for a variety of reasons, such as:

- indexes on the table need to be updated
- triggers are on the table are executed (unlikely if you are just creating the table)
- other activity on the server
- the number of rows that are being passed into the server

I would recommend that you combine the inserts into a single query.  You can do so using `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into table(col1, . . . coln)
    select . . .  union all
    select . . .  union all
    . . .;
```

If you are just declaring columns in the table, you can combine this all into one statement:

```
create table xxx as
        select . . .  union all
        select . . .  union all
        . . .;
```

Comment: `other activity on the server` You do realize that SQLite doesn't have servers?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo . . . "other activity on the computer".  That was meant to be a generic term that refers to the computer running the database software.

Comment: @Geza . . . The last solution of putting the `inserts` into one statement should have similar performance to putting them into one transaction.  Your original question was quite broad, which is why this answer is broad.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I just upvoted your answer, as it is definitely informative. I believe some of your suggestions could be excluded based on my question - but you may disagree. Anyhow, thanks again for taking the time to answer!